# Dataframe join on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I don't know if this could be consider a join/merge/concatenate or something else but this is what is happening:
I have two pandas dataframes (df1, df2) and I am trying to put them together so I could have something similar to the result below:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1], 'column A': ['item_a', 'item_b']})
```

| index | column A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | item_a |
| 1 | item_b |

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1, 2], 'column B': [11, 22, 34]})
```

| index | column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 34 |

Desired Output:

| index | column A | column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | item_a | 11 |
| 1 | item_a | 22 |
| 2 | item_a | 34 |
| 3 | item_b | 11 |
| 4 | item_b | 22 |
| 5 | item_b | 34 |

I tried most of the regular (`merge`, `concat`, etc.) and I still can't figure out what I was doing wrong?

Does anyone have any idea of what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a cross merge:

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='cross').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   index  column A  column B
0      0    item_a        11
1      1    item_a        22
2      2    item_a        34
3      3    item_b        11
4      4    item_b        22
5      5    item_b        34
```

---

Note that `how='cross'` requires pandas 1.2.0+. For earlier versions, create a dummy column to merge on:

```py
(df1.assign(key=0)
    .merge(df2.assign(key=0), on='key')
    .drop(columns='key')
    .reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output is a classic cartesian product of two lists. In general you can create with list compression

```py
data = [[a, b] for a in df1['column A'] for b in df2['column B']]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column A', 'column B'])
```

```
print(df3)

  column A  column B
0   item_a        11
1   item_a        22
2   item_a        34
3   item_b        11
4   item_b        22
5   item_b        34
```

With `itertools.product()`

```py
import itertools

data = [[a, b] for a, b in itertools.product(df1['column A'], df2['column B'])]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['column A', 'column B'])
```

```
print(df3)

  column A  column B
0   item_a        11
1   item_a        22
2   item_a        34
3   item_b        11
4   item_b        22
5   item_b        34
```

With `pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`

```py
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['column A'], df2['column B']], names = ["column A", "column B"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()
```

```
print(df3)

  column A  column B
0   item_a        11
1   item_a        22
2   item_a        34
3   item_b        11
4   item_b        22
5   item_b        34
```